# ASP.NET MVC : how to get list of an items from other model by Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, filter, model

I have two models: Picture.cs

```
    public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

And User.cs

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

In a `List<Picture>`, I want to get all pictures with `UserId = User Id`, but instead of it I get all pictures in the database that I have.

Comment: please post your current attempt at accomplishing what you're trying to accomplish. hopefully that helps clear your question up as right now it isn't very clear (the posted answer by @Javi seems perfectly reasonable based on the information you've provided)

Comment: Thank you, but it is not solving my problem for multiple users list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you already have a `List<Picture> allPictures`, you would simply use `linq` to filter the listed based on userid:

`List<Picture> picturesForUser = allPictures.Where(x => x.UserId == someUserId).ToList()`

or you can query them directly from the database as @Javi suggested:

`List<Picture> picturesForUser = yourDbContext.Pictures.Where(p => p.UserId == someUserId).ToList();`

Comment: The problem is I will get the list of users and I can't make this list for multiple users that is why I'm trying to get pictures list for all users from my model.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Picture> myList = yourContext.Picture.Where(p => p.UserId == yourUserId).ToList();
```

yourContext would be the instance of your Database.
And yourUserId could be your Model.User.Id, depending on how you have done it

Comment: Yes, I know how to make list from a controller, but how I make it from my models?